# Uniform Initialization Syntax Not Working on Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2012, most-vexing-parse, uniform-initialization

[c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) introduced [Uniform Initialization Syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse#Uniform_initialization_syntax) as an explicit way to work around the [Most Vexing Parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).

I believe http://en.cppreference.com refers to it as [Direct List Initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization).

Anyway whatever you call it it doesn't seem to work in [visual-studio-2012](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2012). Given this example:

```
istringstream foo("192 168 1 1");
const vector<int> bar{ istream_iterator<int>(foo), istream_iterator<int>() };

cout << bar.front() << endl;
```

I get the error:

> error C2601: `bar` : local function definitions are illegal

If I instead do: `const vector<int> bar(istream_iterator<int>(foo), istream_iterator<int>());` I get the error:

> error C2228: left of `.front` must have class/struct/union

I can work around this with the pre-[c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) workaround: `const vector<int> bar((istream_iterator<int>(foo)), istream_iterator<int>());` But I find it frustrating. Is Uniform Initialization Syntax not implemented for [visual-studio-2012](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2012)?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Yeah... that's an `initialization_list` question. This isn't.

Comment: The syntax is not applied consistently anyway: iterators can use `{}` too, or even better, `istream_iterator<int>{foo}, {}`, the latter will be inferred.

Comment: @Incomputable I actually tried that and still get the exact same errors, through that doesn't seem necessary elsewhere.

Comment: My first comment was wrong, VS2013 was the one that rolled back support for default member initializers in an [update](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2014/08/19/the-future-of-non-static-data-member-initialization/). VS2012 just [doesn't support](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368(v=vs.110).aspx) list initialization.

Comment: @Praetorian So I see "Initializer Lists" in the unsupported features. I understood "Uniform Initialization Syntax" to be separate from that.